# AppleScript - Geographic Location

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to write a script that identifies my location? I am trying to make an if statement that lets my laptop find my location at a certain time and tell me things I need to do at that location

Comment: With vanilla AppleScript it's not possible.

Comment: Perhaps utilize a command-line utility such as [whereami](https://github.com/victor/whereami). and shell out the command(s) via AppleScript using the [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may request for you to authorise *Script Editor* to have access to your location service (don't forget to turn Location Services on), so you may need to run the script a second time once access has been granted.

```
use framework "CoreLocation"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property this : a reference to the current application
property nil : a reference to missing value
property _1 : a reference to reference

property CLLocationManager : a reference to CLLocationManager of this
property kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers : a reference to 3000.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property running : false
property result : missing value -- Lat./long. or error description
property number : 0 -- Error code
property seconds : 10 -- Maximum time to allow script to run
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IMPLEMENTATION:
my performSelectorOnMainThread:"getLocation" withObject:nil waitUntilDone:true
return my result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HANDLERS & SCRIPT OBJECTS:
to getLocation()
    set locationManager to CLLocationManager's new()

    locationManager's setDelegate:me
    locationManager's setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

    set my running to true
    set started to current date

    locationManager's startUpdatingLocation()

    repeat while my running
        delay 0.5
        if (current date) - started > my seconds then exit repeat
    end repeat
end getLocation

on locationManager:locationManager didUpdateLocations:locations
    local locationManager, locations

    locationManager's stopUpdatingLocation()

    set my running to false
    set my result to (locations's valueForKey:"coordinate") as record
end locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

on locationManager:locationManager didFailWithError:err
    local locationManager, err

    tell err's code()
        set my number to it
        set my result to item (it + 1) in my enum's kCLError
        if it ≠ 0 then set my running to false
    end tell
end locationManager:didFailWithError:

script enum
    property kCLError : {¬
        "Location Unknown", ¬
        "Denied", ¬
        "Network", ¬
        "Heading Failure", ¬
        "Region Monitoring Denied", ¬
        "Region Monitoring Failure", ¬
        "Region Monitoring Setup Delayed", ¬
        "Region Monitoring Response Delayed", ¬
        "Geocode Found No Result", ¬
        "Geocode Found Partial Result", ¬
        "Geocode Canceled", ¬
        "Deferred Failed", ¬
        "Deferred Not Updating Location", ¬
        "Deferred Accuracy Too Low", ¬
        "Deferred Distance Filtered", ¬
        "Deferred Canceled", ¬
        "Ranging Unavailable", ¬
        "Ranging Failure"}
    property CLAuthorizationStatus : {¬
        "Not Determined", ¬
        "Restricted", ¬
        "Denied", ¬
        "Authorized (Always)", ¬
        "Authorized When In Use"}
end script
---------------------------------------------------------------------------❮END❯
```

If the return message is "Location Unknown", this may indicate you need to [reset your network settings](https://mandarapte.com/apple/reset-rebuild-network-settings-preferences-including-ethernet-wifi-bluetooth-system-default-mac-macintosh/).

Comment: @user3439894 I've updated the script to record but otherwise ignore a `kCLErrorDomain error 0` and persist with trying to find your location for a maximum length of time stipulated by the script property `seconds`.

Comment: Not bad, the LAT,LON returned was ~100 FT off my actual location. That's worth a +1 :)

Comment: from the script editor it is working fine when I execute the script using osascript it gives missing value or denied what permission to give

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in macOS 13 (Ventura). (I used this with osascript in shell scripts for other users that don't have any third-party tools like CoreLocationCLI installed.) Apple seem to have locked down Location Services pretty tight now, and it's also very hard to get (for example) CoreLocationCLI to work.